# Application of Burnside's theorem? Composition factors of $|G|=p^2q$ are...

Tags: group-theory

Continuing for my study on practicing group theory...
I am now stuck on this problem about composition factors,

> $G$ is a group such that $|G|=p^2q$ where $p \neq q$ and $p,q$ are prime. Prove that the composition factors of $G$ are $C_p,C_p,C_q$ in some order.

Well, Burnside's theorem tells me that such a $G$ is soluble as $2,1$ are not negative. But I'm stuck with proceeding to the "main" bit, namely to show that the factors are specifically $C_p,C_p,C_q$ in some order.

Does anyone know how to go about showing this? And in what order it is?

Help is very much appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you have a serious misunderstanding of several things here, based on your comment about the exponents not being negative. Also, if you know what it means to be solvable, then it should really be trivial to show this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Oh, do I? Sorry I am new to the theorem, I'll try looking into it some more...

Comment: No, based on that comment, you seem to have a misunderstanding about what the order of a group even is.

Comment: Um, isn't the order of a group $G$ denoted $|G|$ and is the "number of elements in the group"? If not please correct me.

Comment: Yes. So how would it ever make sense for any of those exponents to be negative?

Comment: no indeed. But then, what does it even mean in this context of Burnside to be "negative" then? It just says "negative" and doesn't explain in my notes. And my knowledge of the word negative is limited to what I have said above.

Comment: It does not say negative. It says non-negative. But the important part is not that they might have been negative but that there might have been more primes.